# How to retrieve script name using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, server, request-uri

I am using Object Oriented PHP for a project which I am developing on my local system. Path to the project in my system is :

```
localhost/ecommerce/
```

I am retrieving the file name using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] which gives me the output :

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
print_r($uri);
```

Output is : /ecommerce/
But output I want is : /ecommerce/index.php

By applying some more operations and removing the Backslashes from the current output I can extract "ecommerce". However, I want to get only the term "index".
My question is how to get the complete path

```
/ecommerce/index.php
```

using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: You can use `basename(__FILE__, '.php'); ` in your index.php. It will return `index` and for the  complete path you can use  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . __FILE__`

Comment: Welcome to the site! Although it is polite to thank users, please avoid adding "Thanks" to posts. This helps keep Stack Overflow clutter-free.

Comment: @Allkin Actually, It is under a method process() in class Url as in
`code
class Url
{
public function process()
{
  $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// further working
}
}
`
So now if I use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . __FILE__ then it gives me output as path to Url class.

Comment: Maybe $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] will help you